# What does the symbol $\gg$ mean in Konyagin and Shkredov's paper on the sum-product estimates?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, notation

The first page of [Konyagin and Shkredov (2016)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.03473) gives the Erdos–Szemeredi conjecture as the claim that for any finite set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon > 0$,
$$\max\{|A+A|,|AA|\} \gg |A|^{2-\epsilon},$$
but they do not define the relation $\gg$ (which they use throughout the paper) between two real numbers. What do they mean? The symbol is usually used to mean "much greater than" in the context of some kind of approximation or limit, but I've never seen it used between two fixed real numbers in a formal theorem without explanation.

Answer (score 1):

$f \ll g$ means $f = O(g)$, the same as [big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

See the first page [here](https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/Solymosi.pdf) for a source (and an exposition of Solymosi's work towards the conjecture!).

Comment: Except big O notation is defined for *functions* (e.g. sequences), not individual numbers. This paper uses the exact same confusing notation as the original one when it says "since $|A \cdot A| \ll |A|^2$ for any set $A$" without explaining what that means.

Comment: Oh, whoops. The function variable is implicitly the size of the set. "For every $\epsilon$, there is $C$ and $N$ so that for $|A| > N$, then $\max\{|A + A|, |AA|\} \geq C |A|^{2 - \epsilon}$".

Comment: Hmm, my intuition would have been to quantify the $N$ under the "for every", not the "there exists". Could you clarify the dependencies between $C$, $N$, and $\epsilon$?

Comment: Anyway, the statement "$|A \cdot A| \ll |A|^2$ for any set $A$" is clearly nonsensical as stated, so I think both papers are being sloppy to the point of being incorrect - even in the abstract!

Comment: (Also, the paper you link to utterly fails to convey any mathemtical ideas in a way that can fit onto a bar napkin as claimed.)

Comment: The result is asymptotic and only applies for large enough $A$ rather than all $A$, hence "there exists $N$". Meanwhile, $\epsilon$ is allowed to go to 0 to express that "it's essentially $|A|^2$" (even though $|A|^2$ itself isn't achievable). I can't defend the paper's notation, but it should be noted that different fields have different standards and expectations about what is implicit to their readers.

Comment: As a side note, this (as well as use of $\sim, \lesssim, \gtrsim$ in this paper) is not standard for asymptotic analysis as a whole. Maybe it's standard for arithmetic combinatorics. Usually $f(n) \ll g(n)$ means that $\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} \to 0$ in the implied limit as $n \to \infty$: $f(n) = o(g(n))$. Similarly, when $\sim$ is not redefined as it is in this paper, $f(n) \sim g(n)$ usually means $\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} \to 1$.

Comment: Holy crap, the statement only holds asymptotically? That was not at *all* obvious to me. I'm going to downgrade their "for any set $A$" phrasing from "annoyingly imprecise" to "actively misleading".

Comment: Are you sure that it only holds asymptotically? The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Szemer%C3%A9di_theorem) for the closely related Erdős–Szemerédi theorem claims that the result holds for all $N$, although it annoyingly does not give the actual value of $c$ for any $\epsilon$, which makes it difficult to search for a counterexample.